# What does ampersand before closing bracket do in C++ function declaration?

Tags: c++, reference, ampersand, function-declaration

Found this example and wonder what the `&` before the closing bracket does?

```
void f(const Foo &)
{
    std::cout << "f(const Foo&)\n";
}
```

Example taken from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)

Help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++, if you don't use a parameter, you don't have to name it.  Some compiler settings even generate warnings if you do name them.  An unnamed parameter only consists of a type and the type can also be a pointer or a reference or combinations of them.  In this case (as already answered), the type is a reference.

Unused parameters are mostly useless and should be avoided, but they can exist in virtual functions, where some implementations need them and others don't.

Comment: Thank you very much. I hadn't come across unnamed parameters in C++ yet. You helped clear that up pretty neatly.

Comment: I also found a [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12186698/on-unnamed-parameters-to-functions-c) explaining a bit about unnamed parameters - for all those that might marvel at them as I do.

Answer (score 1):

Its a reference to type Foo. You should get yourself a C++ book and read through it.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28C%2B%2B%29

Answer (score 1):

In simple terms the  `&` says it's a reference.

So when you use the & operator in the function declaration, preceded by a type(*here it is Foo*) it means "reference to" which is essentially an automatically dereferenced pointer with disabled pointer arithmetic.

Also check this [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/25999/) for details