# Why are unnamed parameters useful?

Tags: c++, function, parameter-passing, most-vexing-parse

I am confused why you can define a function like

```
int func_useless(int) { return 2; }
```

that takes as input an unnamed int, but does nothing with it, unlike

```
int func_useful(int a) { return a; }
```

For instance, you could call

```
int x = func_useless(3); // x is 2
```

where passing an int to `func_useless` was required but results in nothing.

When would passing something that cannot be used ever be useful? Why is this a feature of the language?

Comment: So, "why are unnamed parameters useful"?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12186698/on-unnamed-parameters-to-functions-c

Comment: This question is a duplicate, but unlike "On unnamed parameters", the question is actually a specific question about the usefulness of unnamed parameters, which is helpful for people trying to figure out why this is useful.

Answer (score 2):

- Callback interfaces; another library may require a callback with a particular signature, but your callback doesn't care about the value of a particular argument.
- When you only care about the type of the argument but not its value.

  - perhaps because all values of that type are equivalent, e.g., `std::nullptr_t`, or tag types like `std::allocator_arg_t` or `std::nothrow_t` or `std::piecewise_construct_t` or `std::input_iterator_tag`.
  - perhaps because the argument is only used to control overload resolution, for example:

    ```
    template<class T> 
    auto do_foo(const T& t, int) -> decltype(t.foo()) { return t.foo(); }
    template<class T>
    void do_foo(const T& t, long) { /* default implementation */ }

    // call t.foo() if valid, otherwise provide a default implementation
    template<class T>
    decltype(auto) foo(const T& t) { return do_foo(t, 0); }
    ```

    The value of the second parameter of `do_foo` doesn't matter; it's only used to control overload resolution for the `do_foo(t, 0)` call when both `do_foo`s are viable, by making the first one better.

    In the same vein we have `operator++()` (prefix) and `operator++(int)` (postfix) and their `--` counterparts; implementations of the postfix `++`/`--` operators rarely if ever care about the value of the `int` parameter; it exists to disambiguate prefix and postfix.

Comment: Some implementations of SFINAE as well.

Answer (score 2):

one use is tag-dispatching, which is a useful technique in template programming:

```
#include <iostream>

struct ping_type {};
struct pong_type {};

static constexpr ping = ping_type {};
static constexpr pong = pong_type {};

void action(ping_type) {
  std::cout << "ping" << std::endl;
}

void action(pong_type) {
  std::cout << "pong" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    action(ping);    
    action(pong);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a use-case.  You have a function that takes a function, and does something with it:

```
int sumFrom0To9(int *func(int)) {
    int acc = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { acc += func(i); }
    return acc;
}
```

You can pass in any single-arg function you want, including, say, something like this:

```
int identity(int) { return 1; }
```

Comment: I won't name that function `identity`... `one` seems better.

Answer (score 1):

Unnamed parameters can sometimes be useful if you want to preserve the binary interface of a function (not change its signature) but no longer have any use for the argument and want to shut up compiler warnings about unused arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any reason that would be useful either.

What I anticipate you are getting at is the most vexing parse:

```
int main()
{
    int funk1();
    int funk2(int());

    funk2(funk1);
}
```

This is a declaration, and you don't need the names here.  They are likely named at point of definition.

Edit:

Actually I did think of a use:

```
int whatnot() { return 6; }

void somefun(int (*callback)(int()))
{
    callback(whatnot);
}

int my_callback(int()) { return 42; }

int main()
{
    somefun(my_callback);
}
```

`my_callback` doesn't need or use the function parameter but it needs to accept it in order to obey the callback interface as specified by `somefun`.

Comment: Most vexing parse: That was exactly what caused all this confusion, specifically in the context of threading, where you must pass a function to a thread but it gets interpreted as a declaration, like `std::thread t(constructor())`  vs `std::thread t((constructor()))`

Comment: There are tons of usage for thist. tag dispatch and sfinae (in one of it's incarnations) to name a few.