# Assure, function runs under lock_guard

Tags: c++, c++11, mutex

I have a function `foo()` which is called from different places in a heavy multi-threaded environment.

It is modifying some sensitive data but due to the complexity I **cannot** use **inside** this function `std::lock_guard...` - this must be assured by the caller function. The reason is that the function is called several times in a row and the modified data [inside `foo()`] must **not** be touched in the meantime by other thread until the one thread finished all modifications by the several calls of `foo()`.

We all are human - and especially me - and I was thinking about a way how to assure that the function `foo()` is indeed under the `lock_guard...` control and I just didn't forget to lock the scope.

For me - running under gcc and I don't have to consider any platform independent solution - I found this way:

```
auto foo( __attribute__ ((unused)) std::lock_guard<std::mutex> & guardActive ) -> void
{
   ...
}
```

Then, `foo()` must be called like this, otherwise already gcc does not compile it:

```
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lockScope( mutexObject );
    // block of commands calling foo() which must NOT be interrupted
    ...
    foo( lockScope );
    ...
    foo( lockScope );
    ...
    foo( lockScope );
    ...
}
```

**My question:**

Is this way OK, or are there better solutions? Reentrant mutex cannot be used.

Comment: Since no operations are defined on `lock_guard`, there seems to be no reason you are passing `lockScope` (by reference) to `foo()`

Comment: @LWimsey But how do I **assure** `foo()` is running under `lock_guard`? When I don't pass `lockScope` to `foo()` there is the *danger* I forget to lock in the caller function the several calls of `foo()`.

Comment: Requiring the passing of an object just to ensure that it has been created is not an uncommon pattern. Unfortunately I can't remember its name; I thought it was called Witness but it isn't. I think it's a good pattern.

Comment: @AlBundy Since you create the `lock_guard` object before calling `foo()`, that particular instance is under protection of the `mutex`.. Passing it by reference does not change that, although it might indeed help to assure you create the object before every call to `foo()`

Comment: @AlBundy Calling `foo()` multiple times with a single `lock_guard` object serializes the calls. As long as `foo()` is not called recursively, the easiest is to create the guard object inside `foo()`. Calling it multiple times from the same function is not a problem since it is released after each call. I would go with David's answer

Comment: @LWimsey It is **not** possible in a heave multi-threaded environment! No way it works! Check my updated code!

Comment: Being similarly mistake-prone, I've used similar ideas to lock data owned by a particular object.  You may find this interesting reading: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html; in particular the "External Locking" section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am convinced, the way I started was correct. I found this post [On unnamed parameters to functions, C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12186698/on-unnamed-parameters-to-functions-c)
 which more or less confirms me.

Now, I removed the parameter name and it is implemented like this:

```
auto foo( std::lock_guard<std::mutex> & ) -> void
{
   ...
}
```

which I find more elegant because it does not use the gcc extension and it is full C++ compatible.

Comment: I don't understand what passing in an `std::lock_guard` helps.
It has no usable members. Why not `void foo();`?

Comment: @Persixty It assures that there is an existing `std::lock_guard<std::mutex>` object and therefore `foo()` runs under the lock. Due to the fact the lock is not needed in `foo()` there is no need to name the parameter.

Comment: I don't think parameters are for 'assuring' some object exists. It doesn't evidence that the right lock his held. You could (for example) use the any guard. The right model is a transaction wrapper. I'll do an answer...

Comment: @Persixty The solution works for me and is very simple. It _remembers_ me I have to use a lock when calling `foo()`. Of course, I can take a knife and cut my finger - why should I do it and why should I abuse the parameter? You understand?

Comment: I see what you're doing and hey, it works for you as a reminder. If it was a released library I'd say it was eccentric. I'm going to provide an answer using a 'facade' pattern because it's a more formal way of achieving this.
Essentially you make a transaction object that controls the mutex. In code where that's OTT I create methods called `foo_prelocked()` and comment that the lock must be held on call. That's suitable for implementing members that may be called individually such as `foo()` that can be called standalone and locks/unlocks and `foo_prelocked()` in nested calls.

Comment: What happens when someone comes along and writes: `{ std::mutex local_mutex; std::lock_guard<std::mutex> local_guard(local_mutex); foo(local_guard); }`? Hint: bad things

Comment: @Caleth Why should I write code like this? What happens if I take a gun and shoot myself? Hint: bad things. What are you trying to tell me? Again: This is a function for my project which is *NOT* a part of any public library and it never will be. It should only _remind_ me that I have to lock the repeated calls of `foo()`.

Comment: Well mostly because I think your *whole design* is flawed, if you have to go through all these hoops. This is also a rather dangerous solution, the audience for this Q&A is not just *you*.

Comment: This approach can be made safer, e.g. by locking a singleton mutex: `class FooMutex { public: static FooMutex & get(){ static FooMutex instance; return instance; } void lock() { mut.lock(); } void unlock(){ mut.unlock(); } private: std::mutex mut; }` then `void foo(std::lock_guard<FooMutex> &)` really does **force** you to acquire the correct mutex

Answer (score 1):

The most comprehensive approach is to create a 'transaction object'. It's a variant of the 'Delegation Pattern' in which the transaction object coordinates access to an object. It can be thought of as `lock_guard<>` on speed. Like `lock_guard<>` it makes use of RAII to lock and then unlock the object allowing multiple actions to take place inbetween.
Also like `lock_guard<>` optimization is likely to just unwrap all the inline calls and result in code exactly as performant as directly managing the `mutex`.

This example uses `private` to forbid access to the 'lock required' members outside a transaction.

In many cases this will surely be over-engineering particularly given a full implementation requires `FooConstTrans` and `FooTrans` classes depending on the `const` qualification of the referenced object.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <type_traits>

class FooTrans;

class Foo {
public:
    Foo():m_x(0)
    {}

friend class FooTrans;    
private:
    int get_x() const{
        return m_x;
    }

    void set_x(int x){
        m_x=x;
    }

    void lock() const{
        m_mutex.lock();
    }

    void unlock() const{
        m_mutex.unlock();
    }

private:
    mutable std::mutex m_mutex;
    int m_x;
};

class FooTrans final {
public: 
    FooTrans(Foo& foo):m_foo(foo){
        m_foo.lock();
    }

    void set_x(int x){
        m_foo.set_x(x);
    }

    int get_x(){
        return m_foo.get_x();
    }

    ~FooTrans(){
        m_foo.unlock();
    }


    private:
      Foo& m_foo;
};

int main() {

    Foo foo;
    FooTrans ft(foo);

    ft.set_x(3);
    //ft is guaranteeing the next line outputs '3' even if other threads are trying to access foo.
    std::cout << ft.get_x() <<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is breaking a fly on a wheel! My solution - which does not need *ONE* line more of code - meets totally my requirements.

Comment: @AlBundy I agree it is in your case. But I think the question deserves a comprehensive answer. Your solution is an aide-memoire but no actual security. Mine helps enforce the principle. Though obviously can be broken  by declaring multiple transaction objects. I think you're asking a question about a general pattern in concurrent programming that fundamentally has a number of different answers.

Answer (score -1):

If `foo` should always use the same mutex, for example if it's a member function and the class holds a mutex, I would go with this method:

```
void foo() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(someMutex);
    ...
}
```

Otherwise, it's often pushed to the caller of a method/class to moderate calling functions from different threads externally to the call using a lock like so:

```
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(someMutex);
    foo();
}
```

If you really think this is error prone (I don't) you could wrap it in a lambda as a convenience:

```
auto lockedFoo = [&]{ std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(someMutex); foo(); };
```

Comment: I cannot use your solution for my case - locking it inside `foo()` because there will follow other calls of `foo()` from the same thread which **must not** be interrupted by other threads. I updated my question.

Comment: @AlBundy are you saying `foo` is recursive?

Comment: @AlBundy I see. If you need a mutex to protect time outside/between `foo` calls, then you definitely need to just lock outside of the `foo` function. There's no point to accepting a lock as an argument (especially since it functionally serves no purpose). If you want to make it more robust, I suggest a new function which performs the action that locks a mutex and calls foo several times. Perhaps a class which holds a mutex and has different functions which lock and call foo several times. I think your problem is a greater architexture one.

Comment: @AlBundy I'd have to see more of your code. This can be improved with good design... maybe a thread safe class that uses foo to accomplish its functions is in order.

Comment: In this case I have to repeat the code of `foo()`. I was also thinking about this. But for me it is not an option to repeat a code. Implementing as lambda is also not an option because `foo()` is called from several functions.